# How to use group by in Informix?

Tags: informix

I'm going to use the `group by` clause...`max()`.
I'm using Informix version 10.

This is example table: `table_a`

```
col_a col_b  col_c 
  1  20181010  3  
  1  20181030  4
```

I want to retrieve data with a recent date.

I want result :

```
col_a col_b col_c
 1    20181030 4
```

When I use this query

```
#query 1: select col_a, max(col_b), col_c from table_a group by col_a
#result : The column (col_c) must be in the GROUP BY list. 

#query 2: select col_a, max(col_b), col_c from table_a group by col_a, col_c
#result : 
col_a col_b  col_c 
  1  20181010  3  
  1  20181030  4
```

I think can I use MS SQL of `row_num(partition by col_b)`? but 
Informix version 10 can't use `row_num`...

So, I use a join query

```
select a.col_a,a.col_b,a.col_c from table_a a
inner join (select col_a, max(col_b) as col_b from table_a group by col_a) b
on a.col_a = b.col_a and a.col_b = b.col_b
```

I got the results I wanted.

Is there a way to use join?

Comment: Note that Informix 10.00 is long out of date (end of service: 2010-09-30).  More recent versions (11.70, 12.10) support the OLAP functions such as ROW_NUM and windowing functionality like PARTITION_BY.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  You have (when typos are fixed) a working query that uses an inner join, but you're asking for a way to use a join?  Or did you mean "a way not to use join"?  To which the answer is "No; there isn't a way to avoid a join".

Comment: IMHO, use of row_num, ROWID, or any SERIAL type fields for sorting or grouping is not reliable.